# Reduced String - compress

Tags: java, string

I am practicing Strings programming examples. i would like to reduce the given strings. it should eliminate a character if its in even numbers
example: Input - aaabbc, Output should be: ac

I have used HashMap to count and store character and count value and computing using value % 2 then continue or else print the output. But some of the test cases are failing in Hackerrank. Could you please help me identify the problem?

```
    static String super_reduced_string(String s){

    HashMap<Character, Integer> charCount = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    if (s == null || s.isEmpty()) {

        return "Empty String";
    }

    char[] arr = s.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {

        char c = arr[i];

        if (!charCount.containsKey(c)) {
            charCount.put(c,1);
        } else {

            charCount.put(c,charCount.get(c)+1);
        }
    }

    for (char c:charCount.keySet()) {

        if (charCount.get(c) % 2 != 0) {
            output.append(c);
        } 
    }

    return output.toString();

}
```

Comment: *Input - aaabbc, Output should be: ac* - what logic is this?

Comment: Its deleting the matching records

Comment: what happened to `bb` ?

Comment: bb, its repeated twice and eliminate it. if there is 3rd b and there is no other matching then keep it

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in how you are selecting the output. HashSets and HashMaps do not have any ordering associated with them. In your test case, the output could be either ac **OR** ca .

To solve this, you can do a variety of things. The quickest way I see is to take your orignal string, lets say s, and call

```
s.replace(c,"")
```

for ever char you need to remove.

I doubt this is anywhere near the most, or even mildly, efficient way to solve this, but it should work.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I got it because my HashMap is not maintaining the order of insertion. So, it is throwing an error for some test cases.

Comment: Glad I can help